# Pouvons-nous dire « acheter des gâteaux pour la pâtisserie » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions

J'ai eu l'examen du bacc ce matin, et on a cette phrase:

> Hier j'ai acheté des gâteaux......... la pâtisserie

Les choix possibles étaient :

> {A} chez
>
> {B} de
>
> {C} pour

Je crois que la bonne réponse est "pour", si on estime que "la pâtisserie " est une construction, et  qu'elle ne signifie pas le magasin. J'ai vraiment besoin d'aide !

Answer (score 4):

As a French, I'll have answered " Hier, j'ai acheté des gâteaux à la pâtisserie". By the way, there is a problem with tense, you can't says "Hier, " + present, it must be "Hier, " + past.

Since "à" is not a valid answer, let's try other ones:

A - chez. Hier, j'ai acheté des gâteaux chez la pâtisserie. "Chez" has to be used with a person. The correct sentence would have been "Hier, j'ai acheté des gâteaux chez le pâtissier." (Pâtissier means pastry cook)

B - de. Hier, j'ai acheté des gâteaux de la pâtisserie. No problem, it means you bought some pastries which came from the pastry (the building). It's a bit redundant but technically correct.

C - pour. Hier, j'ai acheté des gâteaux pour la pâtisserie. Here it means that you bought pastries in order to bring them to a pastry (the building). While this sentence could be said, you'll never do that.

So if I had to take a guess, I'll say B - de. It's not the perfect answer but it's the best of the three. C - pour could have been too but b - de is more common and correct.

Comment: achete is just an writing mistake....could pâtisserie mean desserts or cakes,  and the meaning is thought to be "j'ai acheté des gâteaux pour le dessert "

Comment: "j'ai acheté des gâteaux pour le dessert " is correct but here dessert refer specifically to the end of the meal.
But in this context, pâtisserie refer to the building where you buy pastries.

Comment: la pâtisserie doesn't mean le dessert. This sentence can not use "pour", the correct answer is B I think.

Comment: But could "pâtisserie " mean dessert,  gâteaux,  bonbons,  candy ? That what i mean

Comment: "Pâtisserie" is a type of dessert. It refers to all types of cold and sweet desserts you can usually buy in a "boulangerie" (bakery).

Comment: It is a type of dessert but does not have this meaning here.

Comment: @guillau4 could you explain a bit more